# jQuery AJAX with PHP Session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a PHP page with a table. Some rows may have a clickable .ggcam "td" element.
This is the jQuery code:

```
$(".ggcam").click(function(){
  $('#campagne').load(document.URL +  ' #campagne');

  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('.loader').show();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "gestione_commesse/redirect.php",
                data: {'tag': id},
                success: function(whatigot) {

                },
                complete: function(){
                $('.loader').fadeOut();
                } 
              }); 

});
```

The code in "redirect.php" is the following:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['tag']=array();
unset($_SESSION['tag']);
$_SESSION['tag']=$_POST['tag'];
```

This code works well, the value is stored correctly in $_SESSION variable.
The problem is that it does not always work. I don't understand, the array variable $ _SESSION is not updated on every click, and I think it's a problem of the ajax call.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Are you sure that all your `<td class="ggcam" ` lines also have an `id="???"` attribute

Comment: <td class="ggcam" id="123"> its something like that??

Comment: @JamieSterling I tried your solution. No effects.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, something like this

Comment: It wasn't to fix the problem, it's just to make it neater.

Comment: @devpro Yes, like this. I have a <td id='1' class='ggcam'></td><td id='2' class='ggcam'></td>. Sometimes it seems to want a slow double click to apply changes.

Comment: A slow doubleclick will likely issue 2 **click** events

Comment: Also you could reduce your PHP code to `session_start(); $_SESSION['tag']=$_POST['tag'];` but that wont fix the issue

Comment: I checked ... no sign of two click events.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. 
I moved the load() call after the ajax call.

It seems to work, thanks for support.